# Retrieve answer from a python url request

Tags: python, http, curl

I want to convert the following curl instruction into python code:

```
curl -X POST --insecure -H "Content-Type:audio/wav" --data-binary 'audio_test.wav' 'http://localhost:8888/file?l=atc&ac=atc'
```

This curl command returns: "One two five"

So, after some reseaches I decided to use the requests library. I made the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8888/file?l=atc&ac=atc'
with open('audio_test.wav','rb') as fichier:
    payload = fichier.read()
head = {'Content-Type':'audio/wav', 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'}
req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=head)
print(req)
```

And it gaves me: <Response [200]>. So I assume that it works.

However I don't have any ideas of how to retrieve the result ("One two five" ) from this since the curl command did it automatically.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `req.text`?....

Comment: Well, thanks you, it works. So simple ! I didn't realazed that req was an object !